# Appending Columns to xls and xlsx file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, excel

I want to programmatically append 3 new columns to present xls/xlsx file. Any idea on how to do it in Ruby? (Ruby V 1.8.7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simple_xlsx_writer gem to generate and append data into xls files.

```
 $gem install simple_xlsx_writer
```

Refer this [DOC](http://www.getharvest.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-generate-excel-files-with-ruby/) for more of this gem usage and methods.

Comment: is require 'simple_xlsx_writer' correct? Because it is giving me no such file to load -- simple_xlsx_writer error.

Comment: Its require 'simple_xlsx'
and the gem name is simple_xlsx_writer    Refer the DOC for more details

Comment: This library look very old. Here is my question regarding this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49233416/best-way-to-convert-csv-file-into-xlsx-and-provide-both-formats-as-export-for-us

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll find the [Ruby Spreadsheet](http://spreadsheet.ch/) library a good starting point.

Comment: Spreadsheet library is super complex and plus i tried appending using spreadsheet library but no luck.

Comment: I am also searching for a solution to a: convert a CSV file OR b: generate a file like `CSV.generate` .