# Best way to convert CSV file into XLSX and provide both formats as export for user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, csv, export-to-excel, xlsx

I implemented a CSV exporter which works like the following:

1. User triggers CSV export
2. App creates a new background job
3. Job generates CSV using `CSV.generate`
4. Job saves file on Amazon S3 with paperclip (assign file with `StringIO`)
5. User can download CSV after job is done

This process works well!

### Now I need to provide an xlsx export as well

I just tried to change the content type for the file to an xlsx format, but I got Content Spoofing errors with paperclip. I am also struggling to set the content type that it works on Windows and Mac machines. I researched a bit and found the following plugins:

- https://github.com/if1live/csv-xlsx-converter only a CLI
- https://github.com/scpike/excel2csv last commit 3 years ago
- https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet Is that the way to go ? Commercial license costs ?
- https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL Anybody has running in production ?
- https://github.com/zenkay/simple-spreadsheet can only read files
- https://github.com/randym/axlsx Looks pretty good, but how to write into files ?

### What I need:

- Way to convert CSV into XLSX OR Simple XLSX generator like `CSV.generate`
- Generating file, which has correct content-types (LibreOffice, Microsoft Office, Numbers should be able to open the file without errors)

### My current CSV generation

```
# data var filled up with with customers
CSV.generate(options) do |csv|
  csv << [
    'header 1',
    'header 2'
  ]
  data.each do |obj|
    csv << [
      obj.attr1,
      obj.attr2,
    ]
  end
end

file = StringIO.new(data) #mimic a real upload file
file.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type } #add attr's that paperclip needs
file.original_filename = "customer-export.#{customer_export.params['format']}" #assign filename in way that paperclip likes
file.content_type = content_type # text/plain for CSV and ? for XLSX

# the file can be assigned to an paperclip attachment and this works for now perfect
```

BTW: Ruby 2.2, Rails 4.1

Comment: If you'd like, I can expose a web service to take a CSV and return an XLSX. Let me know if this is of interest...

Comment: A web service is not a option. The fill process is already implemented for CSV. We just need the 5% to get it work with xlsx